# Can't run ssl - apache

Tags: ssl, apache2

I am trying to install SSL certificate for apache. I have already modified httpd.conf, where I uncommented this line

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

I have also modified this httpd-ssl.conf file. Now, when I want to run ssl by command

```
apachectl sslstart
```

I get this error

```
The startssl option is no longer supported.
Please edit httpd.conf to include the SSL configuration settings
and then use apachectl start.
```

Could someone help me? It seems that I have to forgotten for something, but I didn't find any other lines in httpd.conf relate to ssl

Comment: Have you done what the error message tells you to do? (Specifically the last line)

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the error you get the 'starssl option is no longer supported. Try to execute:

```
apachectl start
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specified the version of Apache I will assume apache 2.4 in a Redhat/CentOS O.S.

I will assume that you know how to create a certificate or that someone has given the certificates and the keys files that you gonna need.

First you need to install and enable mod_ssl.

Install:

`yum install mod_ssl`

Edit /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf and uncomment the following line:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Second edit /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf and ensure at least the following lines:

```
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:run/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
Mutex sysvsem default
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
```

For every VirtualHost that you configure you need to include this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName your.domain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/your.domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/your.domain.com.ersa
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/yourCA.crt
...
# Lots of configs
...
</VirtualHost>
```

And test your configuration with:

```
apachectl configtest
```

Then if everything went ok restart apache.